# Why Database Dropcolumn Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, database, model-view-controller, entity

I am trying to add an image to my database on my online web shop (I want all the details for the product to be in my database so I can use the data on several places - I am trying to follow the DRY-principle). First I tried with "Add-Migration Image". But it drops the lines with the image. Why is that?

Here is my `Product` entity:

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter an product name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please specify a category")]
    public string Category { get; set; }

    public string SubCategory { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required
    (ErrorMessage = "Please enter a positive price")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public byte[] Image { get; set; }

    public string ImageSourceFileName { get; set; }

    public string ImageContentType { get; set; }
}
```

Here it was happen. The database first takes the new lines than it drops them. Why is that? And what shall I do differently?

```
public partial class Image2 : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<byte[]>(
            name: "Image",
            table: "Products",
            type: "varbinary(max)",
            nullable: true);

        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
            name: "ImageContentType",
            table: "Products",
            type: "nvarchar(max)",
            nullable: true);

        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
            name: "ImageSourceFileName",
            table: "Products",
            type: "nvarchar(max)",
            nullable: true);
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
            name: "Image",
            table: "Products");

        migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
            name: "ImageContentType",
            table: "Products");

        migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
            name: "ImageSourceFileName",
            table: "Products");
    }
}
```

In the end I want to be able to add an image in the Create-Edit-Delete-Views.

This is my process:

1. First update the database with the Image-rows.
2. Change the controller and the views so they can handle the image.

See above.

Answer (score 0):

Your migration contains two parts, up and down.

Up is the part that adds the new changes to your database.

The *down* part is the part you use to *undo* those changes. So if you want to roll back your migration, the *down* method is called. Logically, rolling back means dropping the newly added columns.

As long as you do not roll back to a previous version, the *down* method is never called.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I see - but how do I only do changes. I used "Add-Migration Image" in the console.

Comment: I thought a little more about this. Is there a roll back-call in "Add-Migration Image" - I don't see that?

Comment: You only do the roll-back if you migrate to an old version like `update-Database -TargetMigration:"OldVersion"`. You can think of the `Down` method as the _uninstall_ files that are put on your PC when you install a program. You never use those until you _remove_ the program.

Comment: Now I see what I might have done wrong. Thank you for your swift and accurate help!